# Which one is correct? "many privileges" vs. "much privilege"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, connotation

Which one is correct? Is it ***many privileges*** or ***much privilege***?

e.g.

> You have ***many privileges/much privilege*** as a child of a rich family.

Comment: One's talking about quantity and the other is quality, which one are you intending it to be?

Comment: Both are non-idiomatic. Normally _a lot_ would be used for both. _Much_ and _many_ are far  more common in negative contexts: _not much_ and _not many_ are fixed phrases, but nobody would say _You have many leaves on your lawn_, though the negative is fine.

Answer (score 2):

***Privilege*** can be used as a countable or as an uncountable noun. Both your phrases are correct, but they bear different connotations:

> *privilege*
>
> 1. [**countable**] a special right or advantage that a particular person or group of people has
>
> - You can enjoy all the benefits and ***privileges*** of club membership.
>
> 2. [**uncountable**] (***disapproving***) the rights and advantages that rich and powerful people in a society have
>
> - As a member of the nobility, his life had been one of wealth and ***privilege***. ([OxfordL](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/privilege_1#:%7E:text=1%5Bcountable%5D%20a%20special%20right,and%20privileges%20of%20club%20membership.))

So, if you'd rather be neutral and simply state that as a child of a rich family you have certain advantages, use ***many privileges***. If you want to point out that a rich family gives the child a superiority of which you disapprove, then use ***much privilege*** (as an uncountable noun).